# VB.Net Running a task on a different thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm developing a small database management tool. I'd like the application to start up and attempt to connect to the database, but the database resides on a networked drive, so it can take a long time. During this time, the application hangs.

I'm using the below code to try and run the code to connect to the database in a different thread so that the application can load, and the database can connect separately.

```
Public Class Incident_Form

    'DELEGATE CLASSES
    Delegate Sub UpdateTable()

    'DELEGATE VARIABLES
    Public UpdateTableVar As UpdateTable

    Private Sub Incident_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        I_List.DataSource = Nothing
        Display_Module.Maximise_Window()

        Splash_Panel.BringToFront()

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

        UpdateTableVar = New UpdateTable(AddressOf Me.UpdateTableHandler)

        Me.Invoke(Me.UpdateTableVar)


    End Sub



    Public Sub UpdateTableHandler() 'Handles the background work for updating I_LIST
        If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
            Me.Invoke(UpdateTableVar)
        Else
            Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_Connection_String)
            myCon.Open()

            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim sql As String

            sql = "SELECT [IN_REF], [Incident Name], [Date Created], [Created By] " & _
            "FROM [Master_Record]"

            adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, myCon)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            I_List.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

            I_List.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
            I_List.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Reference"

            I_List.Sort(I_List.Columns("Date Created"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)

            myCon.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The issue with the above is that although the application loads and displays the form correctly, the user still cannot interact with the form until the database finishes connecting. It's like it's running in another thread but its waiting for that thread to finish before it continues.

Is there something I'm missing or is this not the correct approach?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for the help, I've updated the code to the following and all is working correctly :)

```
Public Class Incident_Form

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet





    Private Sub Incident_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        I_List.DataSource = Nothing
        Display_Module.Maximise_Window()
        Splash_Panel.BringToFront()
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Try
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        Catch ex As Exception
            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        End Try




    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        UpdateTableHandler()

    End Sub


    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        I_List.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        I_List.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        I_List.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Reference"

        I_List.Sort(I_List.Columns("Date Created"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
    End Sub


    Public Sub UpdateTableHandler() 'Handles the background work for updating I_LIST

        Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_Connection_String)
        myCon.Open()


        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "SELECT [IN_REF], [Incident Name], [Date Created], [Created By] " & _
        "FROM [Master_Record]"

        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, myCon)
        adapter.Fill(ds)


        myCon.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: There is no multi-threading going on there.  There are a number of ways to execute code on a secondary thread.  As you're using WinForms there, it seems that a logical option would to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  Do the background work in the `DoWork` event handler and then update the UI if required in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: Yeah, there is absolutely no multithreading going on - also : what is *"delegate classes"* supposed to mean? There is no such thing, classes cant be delegates but **instances** can. In your example, you're basically shifting the work from the main UI thread onto a specific UI control thread - which makes this control hang, instead of your entire UI. Thats called "damage control" :-).
Introduce an actual thread which updates your control **once your data has arrived** and you're good to go ... but you should disable edit-functionality while its still loading.

Comment: Thanks @specializt, updating the control after loading the dataset with the background worker fixed the hanging issue

Comment: you also should introduce pagination ... loading an entire table at once **will** result in performance problems *or even deadlocks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `DoEvents()` call with `BackgroundWorker` by adding it to your form.

```
Private Sub Incident_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    I_List.DataSource = Nothing
    Display_Module.Maximise_Window()
    Splash_Panel.BringToFront()

    Try
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()    
    Catch ex As Exception
        BackgroundWorker1p.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As 
System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    UpdateTableHandler()

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be calling the 'UpdateTableHandler' Sub at all, so the database isn't being contacted?

Comment: Hi @SilverShotBee, I updated my answer to call the method directly instead of initializing it under the DoWork() sub. As you can see, the UpdateTableHandler() method is being called.

Comment: This is all working, but during the update of information from the database, the application still hangs? I'm understanding what we're trying to do, but not why its still hanging

Comment: Have you try to remove the code "If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
            Me.Invoke(UpdateTableVar)" because it might affect and causes the form to hang.

Comment: @SilverShotBee : That's because you're calling `Me.Invoke(UpdateTableVar)` in `UpDateTableHandler()`. Invocation moves the execution from the background thread to the UI thread, which means that you're still running on the UI. You should only use `Invoke()` when you are to access UI elements (=controls).

Comment: One thing that concerns both Richard and @SilverShotBee is that calling `BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()` in the `Catch`-block doesn't do anything unless you check `BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending` in the `UpdateTableHandler()` method. Thus, cancelling a BackgroundWorker operation is done by the programmer, not automatically.

Comment: Noted.Thanks @VisualVincent